# Cant see img on my react - ( code )

Tags: reactjs

I add jquery into my index.html
But i don't know why i can't see the avatar_url and the name of the incoming date

I check - the date is valid ( remove the login name here )

How to see the image and the name ? 
what i did wrong ?

```
var Card = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){
    return {};
  },

  componentDidMount: function(){

    // we need to define the callback info as component => to get the prop/state
    var component = this;

    // get data ( name ) from AJEX info => the return object is the arg 'data' 
    $.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + this.props.login, function(data){

      component.setState(data);    // set component as component of the callback data => in h3 we can get the data to show on ui 


    });
  },

  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        <img src={this.state.avatar_url} width="80"/>
        <h3>{this.state.name}</h3>
        <hr/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});




var Main = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Card login="myLogInName" />
      </div>
    )
  }
});

React.render(<Main />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: can you do a console.log() in your render method and confirm you are getting this.state.avatar_url correctly?

Comment: @G_S new on react ... please tell me how

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eVxxaq its working perfectly. I am getting image

Comment: I see that its work on yours. don't understand my not on my env

Comment: are you seeing any errors in console? and is it your whole component or you removed unnecessary code to make it simple here?

Comment: And why dont you use the ES6 syntax which could be simpler to understand?

Comment: Well you're setting your state with data so you can't access your avatar_url via this.state.avatar_url. try `this.state.data.avatar_url`instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `name` property is `null` in the response. As an alternative I've used the `login` property since it as a value.

I've also updated the code to use ES6 syntax, one advantage of which is arrow functions to auto-bind `this`.

```js
class Card extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      avatar_url: null,
      login: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    // get data ( name ) from AJAX info => the return object is the arg 'data' 
    $.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + this.props.login, data => {
      this.setState(data);
    });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <img src={this.state.avatar_url} width="80"/>
        <h3>{this.state.login}</h3>
        <hr/>
      </div>
    );
  }
};


class Main extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Card login="myLogInName" />
      </div>
    )
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating components using React.createClass was deprecated after the v.16 update for Reactjs.
In order to create a react component in this way, you need to include the `create-react-class` package at the top of your file using `var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');`